# dynamic import() for non-code-splitting applications

Tags: javascript

In an application with code-splitting, dynamic `import()` is used as signals to do code splitting and lazy loading. But dynamic `import()` also exists in non-code-splitting applications.

Is there a TRUE use case in which dynamic import() is useful, i.e., improves dev experience or performance?

```
const ns = await import('./lazy');
```

is transpiled to the following in node.js by default:

```
const ns = await Promise.resolve().then(() => require('./lazy'));
```

Comment: I guess it transpires to this node.js only if dynamic imports are not supported.

Comment: A simple example is feature detection, regular imports can't be conditional.

Comment: Dynamic imports shouldn't be used at random, just because it's new and shiny (if this is what you're getting at). Code splitting and lazy loading are the "true" use cases that improve performance. Some apps will see incredible performance gains from using it.

Comment: @Etheryte The conditional case is a good point.